# Getting undefined trying to get value of JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting undefined trying to access some key inside of my JSON. The issue is because my value is inside of an Array.

I'm using `console.log(jsonTest.data.eventHeader.id)`
I've tried to use `console.log(jsonTest.data[].eventHeader.id)`

JSON Structure:

{ "data": [ { "eventHeader": { "id": "value" } } ] }

NodeJs code:

```
return rp(dataQuery) // simple query
.then((responseQuery: string) => {
JSON.parse(responseQuery);
const jsonTest: any = JSON.parse(responseQuery);
console.log(jsonTest.data.eventHeader.id)
fs.writeFileSync('liferaft-properties', jsonTest.username);
return responseQuery;
});
```

Comment: `console.log(jsonTest.data[0].eventHeader.id)` should work...

Comment: You need an `index` to access the array elements. If you know that it is always the first element, you can do `jsonTest.data[0].eventHeader.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

console.log(jsonTest.data[0].eventHeader.id) worked fine